# VERY odd python NameError

Tags: python, wsgi, pickle, python-2.7, nameerror

I am making a python program to pickle some data and then save it to a file. It isn't working.

```
path="C:/foo/bar"
def newData():
    import pickle
    data = [
        ["foo"],
        ["bar"],
        ["baz"]
    ]
    file = None
    i = 0

    while file==None:
        if not exists(path + str(i)+".data"):
            file = open(path + str(i)+".data", "w+")
        else:
            i+=1
    pickle.dump(data, file)
    close(file)
    return path + str(i)+".data"
```

I get a name error saying that "global name close is not defined":

```
  File "C:/foo/bar/baz.py", line 26, in newData
    close(file)
NameError: global name 'close' is not defined
```

If I comment the line with close in it, I get:

```
  File "C:/foo/bar/baz.py", line 26, in newData
    #close(file)
NameError: global name 'close' is not defined
```

Is my code wrong (yes)? how?

Comment: how 'bout `file.close()`

Comment: @JBernardo Nope. File "C:/foo/bar/baz.py", line 26, in newData
     file.close()
 NameError: global name 'close' is not defined

Comment: If you comment out the line with close() and you're still seeing the error, it's on a different line that you think it is.

Comment: If you have the GNU utilities installed on your system `cat -A C:/foo/bar/baz.py` ought to show the whitespace very clearly -- which is where many of my most confusing Python problems have come from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are editing your file, but your web server is still running the old code.  The traceback reads the source file to show you the line, but that doesn't mean it's running that line.  This is clear from the traceback you mentioned that indicates a comment line as the problem.

As @JBernardo commented, you need to change "close(file)" to "file.close()", and then you need to force your web server to reload the code.

Comment: Deleting the corresponding .pyc file might help, if all else fails.